# Images not displaying on WooCommerce single product page

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I'm facing a situation in my shop page.

https://www.soygorrion.com.ar

Images are not displaying in the single product page of WooCommerce. I can see the thumbnails, but when I click in the product to see it the image does not display.

Example: https://www.soygorrion.com.ar/tienda/bolsos/ombu/

I tried to regenerate thumbnails but it doesn't work. Also I'm able to see the images on the Multimedia page and open them from their link with no problem.

Can someone give me a hint? When I inspect the element from chrome I see that the image URL links are written this way

```
data-default="[{"large":["https:\/\/www.soygorrion.com.ar\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/12\/Pin_Paco-650x650.jpg",650,650,true],"single":
```

Edit: also I tried to deactivate plugins to see if that was the problem.

thank you!

Comment: Have you tried on your local machine with default WordPress theme twentynineteen? From the code above it looks like your theme's WooCommerce code is not rendering properly for images.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem was this CSS code:

```
div.noo-woo-images-wrap {
    display: block;
}
```

`display` was set to `none`.